# SharePoint Webservices using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I use a JQuery dialog box to ask the user a daily question. I have a question and answer list which contains the information to load into the dialog box. I do not want the user to view or edit information in the question and answer list. However i do want to update the answer list based on the selected answer on the popup dialog box that is displayed to the user.

I am using Javascript to update a list using SharePoint webservice. For the users who do not have permissions to view or edit the list is it possible to elevate their permissions to be able to update the answer list based on their selection from the popup dialog box. Is there a way to change the Soap Header to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

Web service calls are made using the current user's credentials, so the only way to accomplish would be to elevate user credentials. You could accomplish that via permissions web service; maybe elevate the permissions, write updates, then revert the permissions back.

If you haven't, take a look at Marc Anderson's (@sympmarc) jQuery library for SharePoint web services - http://spservices.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to imagine that it would be possible to elevate permissions with client side code only.

Just imagine the security implications...

Comment: You know... I hadn't fully thought that through... it would have to elevate based on that users credentials... clearly not going to work...

That's what I get for multitasking...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use item based security. It isn't ideal but neither is your question.

If you create a workflow on item created then you can change permissions accordingly. So everyone has write access but htey only have edit on their own items. assuming you are using sp 2007.